# set-aduser , update several extensionattribute variables plus other attributes at once in powershell script

Tags: powershell, import-csv

So I have a basic script that works when values are hardcoded.  I need some help getting it to work when values are dynamic from a file:

Here is the basic script:

```
 set-ADUser -Identity test.hsi -replace @{extensionAttribute4="LoadedFromInterface";extensionAttribute5="2";extensionAttribute6="2"} -Manager jim.james
```

What I want to do is read from a file using Import-CSV, loading the important columns into variables, checking for null/empty condition and then re-setting the variables if they were null.  Ultimately doing the same as above but with variables that got loaded from the file.  extentionAttribute5 and extensionAttribute6 would both be values from the file (sometimes null) and manager would also be a variable that is assigned from file.

```
Import-CSV C:\Users\user1\Documents\WTKtoAD\WTKtoAD.csv | %{$SAM = $_.SamAccountName;If ($_.PhoneTypeMobile -eq $Null) {$PhoneMobile = "NotProvided"} Else {$PhoneMobile = $_.PhoneTypeMobile};If ($_.PhoneTypeHome -eq $Null) {$PhoneHome = "NotProvided"} Else {$PhoneHome = $_.PhoneTypeHome}} | set-ADUser -Identity $SAM -Add @{extensionAttribute4="LoadedFromKronos";extensionAttribute5=$PhoneHome;extensionAttribute6=$PhoneMobile} -Manager $_.Manager
```

When I run the script I get the following error in Powershell ISE (x86) 'Run As Admnistrator'.

```
PS C:\Users\user1>     Import-CSV C:\Users\user1\Documents\WTKtoAD\WTKtoAD.csv | %{$SAM = $_.SamAccountName;If ($_.PhoneTypeMobile -eq $Null) {$PhoneMobile = "NotProvided"} Else {$PhoneMobile = $_.PhoneTypeMobile};If ($_.PhoneTypeHome -eq $Null) {$PhoneHome = "NotProvided"} Else {$PhoneHome = $_.PhoneTypeHome}} | set-ADUser -Identity $SAM -Add @{extensionAttribute4="LoadedFromKronos";extensionAttribute5=$PhoneHome;extensionAttribute6=$PhoneMobile} -Manager $_.Manager
Set-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
At line:1 char:318
+ ... User -Identity $SAM -Add @{extensionAttribute4="LoadedFromKronos";extensionAttri ...
+                    ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

The file looks like this:

```
> SamAccountName,PhoneTypeMobile,PhoneTypeHome,Manager
> test.hsi,333-234-3433,'',bob.henst
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is because you have put the `Set-ADUser` in the wrong place (AFTER the ForEach-Object).

You can hardly tell from your code because you are putting everything on the same line which makes it very hard to read. My advice is to give it some *air*. That way, mistakes are far easier to spot.

As for the code. I didn't test because I don't have AD available right now but i think this will work better:

```
# this is the content of the WTKtoAD.csv file

# SamAccountName,PhoneTypeMobile,PhoneTypeHome,Manager
# test.hsi,333-234-3433,'',bob.henst

Import-CSV C:\Users\user1\Documents\WTKtoAD\WTKtoAD.csv | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $SAM = $_.SamAccountName
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.PhoneTypeMobile)) { $PhoneMobile = "NotProvided" } else { $PhoneMobile = $_.PhoneTypeMobile }
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.PhoneTypeHome))   { $PhoneHome = "NotProvided" } else { $PhoneHome = $_.PhoneTypeHome }
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Manager))         { $Manager = $null } else { $Manager = $_.Manager }

        $props = @{
            extensionAttribute4 = "LoadedFromKronos"
            extensionAttribute5 = $PhoneHome
            extensionAttribute6 = $PhoneMobile
        }
        Set-ADUser -Identity $SAM -Replace $props -Manager $Manager
    }
```

As you can see, i have also put in a small test for the `Manager`. If in the CSV this is an empty string, it will now **Clear** the manager property for the user.